# How to unpin/remove "Home" from top of Navigation Pane?

Tags: windows-11

How do I unpin/remove "Home"?

[image]

(With "Documents", "Music", "Videos", etc. I could right-click and "Unpin from Quick access". But for "Home", there is no such option.)

Answer (score 0):

this is what I found in my troubleshooting quest:

https://www.elevenforum.com/t/add-or-remove-home-in-navigation-pane-of-file-explorer-in-windows-11.2449/

Please also check out any registry file you download before merging and make sure to back up your registry system before making any changes:

https://www.howtogeek.com/724600/how-to-read-a-reg-file-and-check-if-its-safe/

Here is a brief explanation of the registries inside:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer] "HubMode"=dword:00000001`

This registry edit creates a new value named "HubMode" under the "Explorer" key located in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion` section of the Windows Registry. The value is set to "dword:00000001", which is a hexadecimal value that translates to a decimal value of 1.

Setting this value to 1 enables the "Hub" feature in Windows 11, which provides a centralized location for accessing commonly used features and apps, such as Settings, File Explorer, and the Microsoft Store.

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace_36354489{f874310e-b6b7-47dc-bc84-b9e6b38f5903}]`

This part of the registry edit deletes a registry key named `{f874310e-b6b7-47dc-bc84-b9e6b38f5903}` located in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace_36354489` section of the Windows Registry.

This key is related to the "Homegroup" feature, which was present in previous versions of Windows but has been removed in Windows 11. Deleting this key will remove any remnants of the Homegroup feature from the Windows Explorer interface.

Hope this helps, have a lovely day ahead.