# How to remove "Folders" and some other items in This PC window (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, user-interface, regedit

[image]

Hello, I'm customizing the Windows 10 interface and wanted to remove the circled parts in explorer windows.

I'm guessing that some can be removed via regedit keys.

What should I look for? thanks!

Comment: You can set Explorer to navigate to This PC instead of Quick Access: https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-folder-options-guide/

Comment: The folders are generally used by people. Perhaps just clear Quick Access. That may help.

Comment: You can also get rid of Quick Access by creating a DWORD called **HubMode** and setting it to 1 under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer**: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/remove-quick-access-other-shell-folders-file-explorer/

Comment: @Vinayak that was already done indeed the window shown above is this pc, however I would like to remove entirely that folders and leave only devices and drives... not sure how remove the help area on top...

Comment: You will never be able to enforce any changes on other users profiles.

Comment: @Ramhound I only use one user profile so for me is ok have the change applied only on current user or something like that.

Comment: [HubMode](https://superuser.com/questions/1754973/how-to-unpin-remove-home-from-top-of-navigation-pane) should have been enough. I presume you rebooted after configuring it?

Answer (score 1):

- The items circled in the Navigation Pane can be removed by unpinning them from Quick Access via their context menus:

  [image]
- For a per-user solution that doesn't modify the default or customized Namespace, CLSID-named entries under the key:

  - `<HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideMyComputerIcons>`

  with a `DWORD` value of `1` will hide the corresponding folder:

This **PowerShell** should do the trick(untested, it's late!)

```
$NameSpaceKey = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace'
$HideIconsKey = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideMyComputerIcons'

If (!(Test-Path $HideIconsKey)) {mkdir $HideIconsKey -Force}
$splat = @{
    'Path'  = $HideIconsKey
    'Name'  = ''
    'Value' = 1
}

(Get-ChildItem $NameSpaceKey).PSChildName -like "{*}" | ForEach-Object {
    $splat['Name'] = $_
    Set-ItemProperty @splat
}
```

[image]

Comment: hello what do you mean for you can unpin them from their context menu? also if I put that code inside a .reg file and I run it, it doesn't work.

Comment: That's because that isn't a .reg file, just a capture of **PowerShell** output to show sample name-value pairs...

Comment: Oh, I'm sad now... so I have to create a .reg code in order to be executed... oookay :D

Comment: Hold on...there's a better reg key for this particular purpose.  `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideMyComputerIcons`. It doesn't require admin privileges/elevated process to edit...will post code shortly...

Comment: I know how to edit a registry key and how to export, I was just lazy :P however having a complete code ready to copy pasta would be very useful... also because without comments It's a bit of mess understand what dword corresponds to what. I tried one of that dwords and putting it to 1 cleaned completely my screen ahah, leaving me only with networking and onedrive option. Ah also, maybe could be useful add in the answer that you need to log off or restart the machine to see the effect!

Comment: With `NonEnum`, yes, my list included CLSIDs from earlier testing -- including the `This PC`folder itself (set to`0` in my capture). Pretty powerful key, huh?  Have you run the **PowerShell** code I added in my edit?

Comment: I tried it and it seems to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

---

***The solution I have found is located [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-remove-desktop-documents-downloads-music/7dd2782d-0e61-4e75-a261-5c9da07597e4)***

Since this method requires you to edit the registry, I listed the steps to secure your registry before you modify it.

---

***Disclaimer:**
***Editing the Windows Registry****

***Caution:***
Modifying the Windows Registry can cause system problems, data loss, or system instability. Proceed with extreme care and only if you have a deep understanding of the Registry. Create backups and document changes. If unsure, seek expert assistance. You will solely be liable for any issues resulting from registry edits.

**To manually back up the Windows registry, follow these steps:**

1. Click on the **"Start"** button.
2. In the search box, type **"regedit.exe"** and then press **"Enter."** If you are asked for an administrator password or confirmation, provide the necessary information.
3. In the **"Registry Editor,"** locate and click on the specific registry key or subkey that you want to back up.
4. Next, select **"File"** from the menu, and then choose **"Export."**
5. In the **"Export Registry File"** dialog box, specify the location where you want to save the backup copy. Additionally, enter a name for the backup file in the **"File name"** field.
6. Click **"Save"** to complete the backup process.

**To restore a manual backup of the registry, follow these steps:**

1. Click on **"Start."**
2. In the search box, type **"regedit.exe"** and press **"Enter."** If prompted, provide the necessary administrator password or confirmation.
3. In the **"Registry Editor,"** click on **"File"** in the menu, and then select **"Import."**
4. In the **"Import Registry File"** dialog box, choose the location where you saved the backup copy. Then, select the backup file you want to restore and click **"Open."**

These steps will help you backup and restore your Windows registry when needed.

---

**To access the Windows Registry Editor and modify the required files, you can use the following steps:**

1. Press the **Windows key (Win)** and the **'R'** key simultaneously to open the **"Run"** dialog box.
2. In the **"Run"** dialog, type **"regedit"** and press **"Enter."**

After opening the Registry Editor, navigate to the following location:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace**

In this section of the registry, you will find several keys with complex names. These keys are associated with the folders you see in the Windows Explorer. For instance, one of the keys is associated with the Desktop folder, and it looks like this: **{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}.**

To remove a specific folder from the Windows Explorer window, you can simply delete the corresponding registry key by following the information provided above.

Comment: Does that cover the material that cost me a point?